# Silverlight not loading

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, windows-7

I tried installing silverlight 5 developer runtime but sadly things ended up being a big mess leaving my vs2010 having "catastrophic error" everytime i'm in design view.

I removed everything silverlight related (or think i did. There are no other silverlight toolkits or runtimes installed on the uninstall list).

Now I browsed to a silverligt app and the "get silverlight" link appears and I downloaded and installed the runtime but the silverlight won't load now (no loading icon and the page is just blank). I checked the app on a different pc and it loads fine.

I've tried both 32 and 64 bit runtime (silverlight 5 is the latest afaik) and tried both versions of IE and chrome. I'm on a 64bit win 7 ultimate and vs2010 ultimate. What am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. What I did was:

- uninstall every silverlight related programs installed (blend, silverlight toolkits, developer and user runtime)
- ran CCleaner to get rid of unnecessary entries in the registry.
- repaired/reinstalled Visual Studio (don't need to uninstall this).
- then re-install the necessary silverlight sdks and runtimes.